# Transactions Mined Status in Go Lang

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, golang

I have a private block chain setup. I am calling a smart contract method from Go Lang. I my code in GoLang should wait until the transaction got mined. How I can achieve that.

Regards
AKM

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WaitMined` function here:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.10.20/accounts/abi/bind/util.go#L30-L32